# Where is System.Data.Linq

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7

I am writing a WP7 app and looking to use the Microsoft CE database available under Mango.  I have upgraded my VS10 environment and I am creating apps at version 7.1.

When I go to include the references for the database side of things they are unavailable i.e.

System.Data.Linq 
System.Data.Linq.Mapping

Do I need to install anything here or have I done something wrong. Where should I be looking for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it is not installed correctly. I did the same and was able to find the DLLs. Can you check if the following file is present locally...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Data.Linq.dll

?

Comment: The Microsoft documentation also mentions Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq;  Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq.Mapping;  - but they are not on my machine anywhere?

Comment: In that case, have you tried referencing it directly [using browse to located the dll] in your Project? Does it work?

Comment: By the way, just checked and found that System.Data.Linq.dll contains all the namespaces that you are looking for. Try adding it directly in your VS, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I can see The System.Data.Linq DLL in the directory that you mentioned, but the Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq are nowhere to be seen.  I am just uninstalling and then re-installing the 7.1 SDK to see if this helps.

Comment: Peter, Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq is a namespace, you won't find that assembly anywhere. Just try adding System.Data.Linq.dll and you will have all the namespaces that you are looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4870/discussion-between-rahul-soni-and-peter)